# Specify repeating tokens in Recursive Descent Parser with NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, recursive-descent

I am trying to parse a grammar similar to this.

```
PER -> 'noun' | 'noun1' | 'noun2'

PERS -> PER+
```

This is not a valid grammar for NLTK's recursive descent parser.
How do specifiy one of more repeating tokens in this grammar

Answer (score 1):

try a rule like:

```
PERS -> PER PERS | PER
```

Comment: Did you mean `PERS -> PERS PER` or `PERS -> PER PERS`?

Comment: Both of them doesn't work. When you use PER -> PER PER It goes into infinite recursion.
When I use PERS -> PERS PER it creates a nested dictionary with the level of nesting equaling the number of PER(s)

Comment: i indeed ment sth. like `PERS -> PER PERS` - changed it above. it is true that it will create a nested structure, but you will get a valid parse for every number of PER. If you need to have them on the same level I don't know if there is any other possibility than writing `PERS -> PER | PER PER | PER PER PER | ...`